# Dealing with a string and byte in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I'm working with some python code, and I can't seem to figure out how to get a byte representation, and a string variable to work together.

I have:

```
secret = b'a very secret message'
```

if I redefine this as:

```
myrealsecret = 'Hey there this is a real secret'
secret = b+myrealsecret
```

Why is that? and how can I get whatever value is in `myrealsecret` to play nicely with `secret` as a byte representation?

Thank you.

Comment: Not a dupe........ although i do see where your going with that assumption. im asked how i can use my two variable references together.

Comment: You either need to `.encode()` your string or `.decode()` your bytes, depending on whether you want the result to be bytes or str.

Comment: Well, can you explain what does *how to get a byte representation, and a string variable to work together* mean?  However `b'test'+'text'` raise `TypeError` if you're using Python 3.

Comment: Ah, here's the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/606191/

Comment: Im simply trying to take a variable, like myrealsecret and represent it as a byte, so that i can use it in conjunction with secret var

Comment: please clarify the question. seems like you are are trying to convert string to bytes. but adding b to a string wont help. you should be seeing a NameError on the 'b'. use encode and decode methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the result to be bytes, `encode` the string (default encoding is `utf8`):

```
>>> secret+myrealsecret.encode()
b'a very secret messageHey there this is a real secret'
```

If you want the result to be a string, `decode` the bytes:

```
>>> secret.decode()+myrealsecret
'a very secret messageHey there this is a real secret'
```

Or, just define `myrealsecret` as a bytes object to begin with:

```
>>> myrealsecret = b'Hey there this is a real secret'
>>> secret + myrealsecret
b'a very secret messageHey there this is a real secret'
```

Comment: Finally, someone who didnt just jump to conclusions. This is spot on, thank you so, so much!